# Is there a "machine interface" API to a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

SQL is an interface designed for Humans to write, but databases have first to parse it, and translate it to their concrete implementation before they can use the query. I was appalled to learn that there is no  'machine' API to PostgreSQL. libpq takes queries as a string! So when [sqlkorma](http://sqlkorma.com/) or [s-sql](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/postmodern/s-sql.html) translate their DSL to a string is not a hacky solution is because that is what libpq expects. Are there any efforts to standardise on an API which doesn't take  strings SQL statements as input? Something along the lines of `select(list_of_fields, table)`

Comment: `select(list_of_fields, table)` this is still human readable... What would zou want to achieve that is not possible using the SQL syntax?

Comment: The main drawback I see for a 'string' interface is that when one does bindings or ORM or another program that interacts with the database the problem is translating your DSL/ORM/API into a valid string is a more error prone process than to mapping it to function calls.

Comment: It's even worse than you think -- different RDBMSs have different dialects of SQL so you can't use the same non-trivial SQL code on different RDBMSs.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [ECPG](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/ecpg.html)?

> An embedded SQL program consists of code written in an ordinary
>   programming language, in this case C, mixed with SQL commands in
>   specially marked sections. To build the program, the source code
>   (`*.pgc`) is first passed through the embedded SQL preprocessor, which
>   converts it to an ordinary C program (`*.c`), and afterwards it can be
>   processed by a C compiler. (For details about the compiling and
>   linking see Section 33.10). Converted ECPG applications call functions
>   in the libpq library through the embedded SQL library (ecpglib), and
>   communicate with the PostgreSQL server using the normal
>   frontend-backend protocol.
>
> Embedded SQL has advantages over other methods for handling SQL
>   commands from C code. First, it takes care of the tedious passing of
>   information to and from variables in your C program. Second, the SQL
>   code in the program is checked at build time for syntactical
>   correctness. Third, embedded SQL in C is specified in the SQL standard
>   and supported by many other SQL database systems. The PostgreSQL
>   implementation is designed to match this standard as much as possible,
>   and it is usually possible to port embedded SQL programs written for
>   other SQL databases to PostgreSQL with relative ease.
>
> As already stated, programs written for the embedded SQL interface are
>   normal C programs with special code inserted to perform
>   database-related actions. This special code always has the form:

```
EXEC SQL ...;
```

> These statements syntactically take the place of a C
>   statement. Depending on the particular statement, they can appear at
>   the global level or within a function. Embedded SQL statements follow
>   the case-sensitivity rules of normal SQL code, and not those of C.
>
> The following sections explain all the embedded SQL statements.

---

I seriously wonder why you think you need this. Between prepared statements and the performance of the Postgres Query Parser there is very little optimization to be had. With any non-trivial query the execution of the query will be hundreds of times slower than the parsing.

Comment: That is embedded SQL statements in your C code, not an API for SQL statements.

Comment: It is an converter that converts embedded SQL statements in your C code to the "machine interface" API that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Most RDBMSs have a procedural language that allows the specification of such APIs as:

```
create_customer(customer_name, customer_address, customer_phone_number);

get_customer_id(customer_name);

generate_invoice(order_id);
```

PostgreSQL has PL/pgSQL (and others), Oracle has PL/SQL (and Java), etc., so although the language on the serverside may be different, you could in theory develop exactly the same system in multiple RDBMSs and create APIs in each one that have just about the same interface.

If you want to avoid generating SQL strings in your application then write an API for your database in the appropriate RDBMS procedural language, and use that.

Edit: of course there are also abstractions such as ActiveRecord that will do the translation to SQL for you as well.